# Silverstripe BasicAuth::protect_entire_site loops on Plesk Server

Tags: basic-authentication, silverstripe, plesk

We have moved some Silverstripe websites from AWS to a Plesk environment (requested by client).

One of the sites is a test website protected by this code:

```
BasicAuth::protect_entire_site(true, 'ACCESS_TEST_SITE');
```

Visiting the test website in the AWS environment would result in a HTTP authentication box popping up in the browser. Entering a valid admin username/ password would then allow access to the website.

In the Plesk environment the HTTP authentication box pops up, but entering in a valid admin username/ password results in it popping up again and again.

I'm guessing that some configuration in Plesk is causing this loop but I don't know where to start looking.

Has anyone run into this issue before/ found a solution?

Comment: Can you share what is in domain's error logs? Should be located in /var/www/vhosts/system/yourdomain/logs/

Comment: Does the site work, when you disable `BasicAuth`. It might be another, unrelated error causing this behaviour.

Comment: @wmk - yes, it works fir when BasicAuth is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Plesk there is no need to use a code to force authentication: instead, Plesk offers Password-Protected Directories option:

open Domains > your domain > Password-Protected Directories > click Add Protected Directory.

Leave directory name as / in order to force authentication page for the main domain's page.

To add a certain user/users+passwords, click Add User in Domains > your domain > Password-Protected Directories > open your newly created directory

This way the code to force authentication is not required.